# php new hosting with double quote error

Tags: php, hosting, quote

I have just change my hosting, before all my PHP scripts worked fine

but now i get many mysql error like this:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near column = \'value\'
```

it seems that there is a double quote in some script

there is a way to resolve without update all my PHP scripts?

EDIT: example of PHP code

```
function test( $table,$column, $where ){

if( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) { $where = strip_tags( trim( $where ) ); }
else{  $where = strip_tags( mysql_real_escape_string( trim( $where ) ) ); }

$where = "AND id = '" . $where . "' ";

$query = "SELECT " . $column . " FROM " . $table . " WHERE 1 " . $where . " LIMIT 1";
//...
```

Comment: add the mysql + php code that will make easier to solve !!

Comment: Im sorry, still learning fortunetelling.

Comment: ok i ve posted an example of code, i think the cause is magic_quote o register global

Comment: where are you setting your $table? and what do you see when you echo $query?

Comment: it is only a part of the function, the $table is and $query are ok, the problem is in the $where, insted of call: id = 'abc' it seems is passed id = \'abc\'

Answer (score 1):

You have to either pass the `$table` variable or declare it as global, if defined outside.

```
function test( $column, $where ){
global $table;    

if( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) { $where = strip_tags( trim( $where ) ); }
else{  $where = strip_tags( mysql_real_escape_string( trim( $where ) ) ); }

$where = "AND id = '" . $where . "' ";

$query = "SELECT " . $column . " FROM " . $table . " WHERE 1 " . $where . " LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: it is only a part of the function, the $table is and $query are ok, the problem is in the $where, insted of call: id = 'abc' it seems is passed: id = \'abc\'

Comment: Please print your query

Answer (score 0):

What happens if your function looks like this?

```
function test( $table,$column, $where ){
    $where=stripslashes($where);
    $where = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim( $where )));
    $where = "AND id = '" . $where . "' ";
    $query = "SELECT " . $column . " FROM " . $table . " WHERE 1 " . $where . " LIMIT 1";
}
```